# PyMongo - get 20% (random or not) of the collection

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb, pymongo

I have a big MongoDB collection - 16 GB, 130M rows.

I need to query the DB and get only 20% of the data.

The best option would be to only get every 5th row, but also a random 20% choosing could work.

[Sample](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/#pipe._S_sample) is not a good option, as duplicates are very likely to happen.

Any suggestions? How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want, one option to do it is to use `$setWindowFields`:
1.'$setWindowFields' will go over your entire collection and and will set the `index` on each document
2. `$match` only every 5th document
3. `$unset` `index`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$setWindowFields: {
      sortBy: {_id: 1},
      output: {
        index: {
          $sum: 1,
          window: {documents: ["unbounded", "current"]}
        }
      }
  }},
  {$match: {$expr: {$eq: [{$mod: ["$index", 5]}, 0]}}},
  {$unset: "index"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/AeQ74SqgYmm)

Comment: As I am a complete beginner with MongoDB, could you please elaborate on how and why that works?